# Calling website through Windows Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, service, windows-services

Looking at creating a windows service that will run on an IIS Server. Said service will access an url (mysite.com/mailflow.ashx) every 5 minutes. This is done to get the mailflow going, which is done by accessing the mailflow.ashx file.

Is: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx
what I'm looking for in my scenario or is there another class that will do the job?

Coming from a non-coding background but I want to do this on my own as a learning experience.

Small hints are more than enough.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the HttpWebRequest class is what you need.

Comment: So I'm on the right track then! Thanks for the reassurance :)

Answer (score 3):

Unless you really want to learn coding, I'd recommend simply creating a scheduled task in windows. Make it call the following js script (called wget in my case)

```
var WinHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1");
WinHttpReq.Open("GET", WScript.Arguments(0), /*async=*/false);
WinHttpReq.Send();
WScript.Echo(WinHttpReq.ResponseText);
```

and set the task to start the following program `cscript` with the following arguments `/nologo C:\Path\To\wget.js http://my.url.com`

There are plenty of ways to ping an remote url, so you may decide to use another option (perhaps simply launching then killing a browser) but coding a service really is overkill if this is the only task you need

Comment: That does seem like a good idea if the goal is to avoid coding.
Thanks for the tip!